# How can we pass null parameter into SQL Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql

Hi all I have created a scaler function in which I want pass parameter @aCOURSENAME as null but when I try to execute it without parameter it gives error of insufficient parameter.
why it happening although I am passing null as parameter into function

Here is my function

```
CREATE FUNCTION UFN_XX_GETSTUCOUNT_ONCOURSE(@aCOURSENAME VARCHAR(20) = NULL)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN 

    RETURN (SELECT  COUNT(SID) AS STUDENT  FROM BATCH B  
            INNER JOIN ENROLLMENT E 
            ON B.BATCHID = E.BATCHID
            INNER JOIN COURSE C 
            ON C.COURSEID = B.COURSEID
            WHERE COURSENAME = @aCOURSENAME
            GROUP BY COURSENAME)

END 

GO
```

`SELECT DBO.UFN_XX_GETSTUCOUNT_ONCOURSE()`

without parameter when I execute it gives error of insufficient parameter.

Comment: I think that you will still need to pass in `null` or `DEFAULT`

Comment: What DBMS is your request about? Is this SQL Server? Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Comment: If your parameter is null then your `WHERE` condition is wrong. It should be `WHERE COURSENAME IS NULL`. In order to make it work you need a coalesce function that will replace `NULL` with a valid value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot omit parameters when calling *user-defined* SQL functions(*).  Yes, I know that stinks, and I have no idea why that is (probably some legacy decision in the SQL parser made 30 years ago).  Nonetheless you either have to pass NULL explicitly:

```
SELECT DBO.UFN_XX_GETSTUCOUNT_ONCOURSE(NULL)
```

or "implicitly" using DEFAULT:

```
SELECT DBO.UFN_XX_GETSTUCOUNT_ONCOURSE(DEFAULT)
```

And yes, we all hate this and have been complaining about it for decades.

(* -- annoyingly, some system functions *do* allow optional arguments)